# What is causing ' PG:undefinedColumn: ERROR: ' when doing initial heroku rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Finally got my app deployed to Heroku for the first time. And I'm getting the traditional 'Something Went Wrong'

I then run heroku rake db:migrate

And then I get the following error as the server begins building db schema

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "national_race_id" does not exist

This of course is a column that exists in one of these migration files. App worked completely fine running it locally.

```
$ heroku run rails db:migrate --app politiscale-01
Running rails db:migrate on politiscale-01... starting, run.6665 (Free)
Running rails db:migrate on politiscale-01... connecting, run.6665 (Free)Running rails db:migrate on politiscale-01... up, run.6665 (Free)
D, [2020-07-10T03:58:08.378063 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(902490343136007465)
D, [2020-07-10T03:58:08.390478 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
I, [2020-07-10T03:58:08.391630 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to AddForeignKeyToCandidates (20200415034845)
-- add_index("candidates", "national_race_id")
D, [2020-07-10T03:58:08.401044 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.2ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_candidates_on_national_race_id" ON "candidates"  ("national_race_id")
-- add_index("candidates", "national_race_id")
D, [2020-07-10T03:58:08.407393 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_candidates_on_national_race_id" ON "candidates"  ("national_race_id")
D, [2020-07-10T03:58:08.409029 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(902490343136007465)
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "national_race_id" does not exist
```

Comment: "It works on my local" - are you sure it works when you wipe the DB and do all the migrations from scratch?

Comment: @you need to check ```national_race_id``` when it has been used, is this column available in table?

Comment: It’s not available yet when app attempts to create that table. Do I need to start with the migration file that includes national_race_id and then do the rest? I thought rails would be able to figure this out from scratch. I guess it’s not that simple

Comment: @rock even when I run one migration file at a time, everything works fine until I get to that file then it breaks and throws same error. At the time I run it, the column exists in the national race table so I'm not sure why it won't get passed it

Comment: If you want to bypass migrations you can dump your entire db to heroku. If you don't mind losing any data on the Heroku Database you can do: $ heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --app name_of_app_on_heroku.  Then push your local database and its records to it by:  heroku pg:push name_of_local_db DATABASE_URL --app name_of_app_on_heroku .   Leave DATABASE_URL as is since it's an environment var they assign to your main db.

Answer (score 0):

When prepping a database from scratch, you are better off using `db:schema:load` -- which loads everything from your `db/schema.rb` -- than trying to run all your migrations. That's true locally as well as on Heroku. If you keep your `schema.rb` checked into your repo (like you should), then this should do the trick:

```
% heroku pg:reset
% heroku run rails db:schema:load
```

If you are concerned that the `schema.rb` you pushed might be out of sync with your 'works locally' db, run `rails db:schema:dump` to rebuild the file, check it in to your repo, and push a new image first.